How to make sure I buy in a specific block Solana
I am currently copy trading a very profitable wallet in Solana, I am using Trojan bot to make the automated copy trades. I would like to increase the profits I made making sure the bot buys in the same block as the wallet I am copy trading, as this is a famous character in the crypto space every time he buys something the volume gets crazy so the buys. Any tips for me to get my buy through the same block as the wallet I am copying??? Very much appreciated your advice
